# Model fit after each "fold" in LOOCV? Multilabel LOOCV by hand

Tags: keras, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I am wondering if it is an issue (possible data leakage?) when implementing leave one out cross validation by hand if the model is fit each iteration after testing on each fold? It seems like if the model is trained on all data except for "X" and after testing on "X" the model is trained on all data other than "Y" and tested on "Y" it has seen "Y" on the first iteration. Is this actually a problem, and does my implementation of LOOCV by hand appear to be correct?

Thanks for your time!

```html
    i = 0
 j = 0
 for i in range(0, 41):
  X_copy = X_orig[(i):(i+1)]  #Slice the ith element from the numpy array
  y_copy = y_orig[(i):(i+1)]
  X_model = X_orig 
  y_model = y_orig
  X_model = np.delete(X_model, i, axis = 0)  
  y_model = np.delete(y_model, i, axis = 0)
  model.fit(X_model, y_model, epochs=115, batch_size=28, verbose = 0)   #verbose = 0 removes learning info
  prediction = model.predict(X_copy)
  prediction[prediction>=0.5] = 1
  prediction[prediction<0.5] = 0
  print(prediction, y_copy)
  if np.array_equal(y_copy, prediction):
   j = j + 1
   #print(y_copy, prediction)
  if np.not_equal:
   #print(y_copy, prediction)
   pass
 print(j/41)  #For 41 samples in dataset
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use this?

```
from sklearn.model_selection import LeaveOneOut

loo = LeaveOneOut()
model =...

test_fold_predictions = []
for train_index, test_index in loo.split(X):
   X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
   y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
   model.fit(X_train, y_train)
   test_fold_predictions.append(model.predict(X_test))
```

EDIT

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Activation
from keras.optimizers import SGD

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(5000, activation='relu', input_dim=X_train.shape[1]))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(Dense(600, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(Dense(y_train.shape[1], activation='sigmoid'))

sgd = SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
              optimizer=sgd)

from sklearn.model_selection import LeaveOneOut

loo = LeaveOneOut()
test_fold_predictions = []
for train_index, test_index in loo.split(X):
   X_train, X_test = X[train_index], X[test_index]
   y_train, y_test = y[train_index], y[test_index]
   model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=5, batch_size=2000)
   test_fold_predictions.append(model.predict(X_test))
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I did try that, but either it doesn't work with a multilabel problem or I can't figure out how to make it work. I should have mentioned that it was a multilabel problem.

Comment: can you post your `y`?

Comment: There are 41 samples in this format. 
[[0. 1. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 1. 0. 0. 1.]
 [1. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 1. 0. 0. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]]

Comment: in general this should not be a problem. What model do you use?

Comment: It's a feedforward NN:

model = Sequential()
 model.add(Dense(500, activation='linear', input_dim=X_orig.shape[1],         activity_regularizer = l1(0.00001)))
 model.add(Activation('relu'))
        kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.1)))
 model.add(Dense(y_orig.shape[1], activation='sigmoid'))
 sgd = SGD(lr=0.0001, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
 model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='sgd', metrics=['accuracy'])